# Resize UV map to real world dimensions using bpy (Blender 2.8)

Tags: python, uv, svg

I'm using `bpy` to script the export of uv maps to `svg`. Afterwards, I want to re-import said uv maps to generate flat models of my curved 3d models.
However, the imported `.svg` curves/meshes are way smaller than the original model. Moreover, there does not seem to be a constant (logical) scaling factor to scale the `.svg` import to fit the original dimensions.

Is it possible to either scale the uv map before exporting to represent the models true size or is there a way to scale the imported `.svg` to fit the models size?

My code looks as follows:

```py
import bpy
import bmesh
import math

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

SliceMe = bpy.context.object.data
SliceBM = bmesh.new()
SliceBM.from_mesh(SliceMe)

uv_layer = SliceBM.loops.layers.uv.verify()

'''
Scale the uv map to fit the models dimension
'''

# Export the Slices uv map as an svg
bpy.ops.uv.export_layout(filepath="/tmp/Curve.svg",export_all=True,modified=True, mode='SVG')

# Clean the .svg up using inkscape
# To merge the curves, inkscape needs a gui. Using Xvfb (X-Server virtual
# frame buffer) create a virtual display for the gui to run in.
# Thus, no windows will pop up
subprocess.run("Xvfb :99 && export DISPLAY=:99 && inkscape -f /tmp/Curve.svg --verb=EditSelectAll --verb=SelectionUnion --verb=FileSave --verb=FileQuit &", shell=True, check=True)

# Re-import said uv map to create flat model of the curved original
bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath="/tmp/Curve.svg")

'''
Scale the import to fit the curved models dimension
'''
```

Thank you!